# Getting a <ul> to expand all the way inside an <li> tag how?

Tags: html, css, menu, frontend

I have an ul inside an li, and I want the ul to expand all the way to the left,right, and bottom of the li, not the top, I want issues to remain visible? I have tried all manner of ways to achieve this but I just cannot do it.

```css
nav > ul {
    width:80%;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul > li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(220, 220, 220), rgb(255, 255, 255));;
    padding: .5em;
    list-style-type: none;
}


.issues {
    /*display: none;*/
    position: static;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.issues li {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .5em .5em .5em 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
            <li>
                <a>Issues</a>
                <ul class="issues">
                    <li><a>x</a></li>
                    <li><a>y</a></li>
                    <li><a>z</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>Press Releases</a></li>
            <li><a>Donate</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Isn't it already visible? Can you provide an example by drawing with paint or something like that?

Comment: You see how the red does not go all the way to the right, left and bottom? There is a sliver of grey on all three of those sides that I want the UL to push to.

Comment: You probably misunderstand some CSS rules that you use: this "small gray margin" is the `padding` you set on the parent `li`. The `ul` then takes all the place it is allowed to. Also you cannot have both between a dimensionned parent and the child that "expands all the way" to fit the parent (what you seem to ask) and a dimension less parent which expands depending on its contant (what you currently have), as these 2 are mutually exclusive

Comment: OK, but the guy that made this site seems to have an UL list inside an LI that has a background color that cover the top LI. I want what he has. https://www.cooperinstitute.ca/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are trying to ignore or suppress the padding style of parent element. This is not a good approach for css but to save the day, you can suppress padding by giving margin to child element like that.

```css
nav > ul {
    width:80%;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul > li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(220, 220, 220), rgb(255, 255, 255));;
    padding: .5em;
    list-style-type: none;
}


.issues {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin:0.5em -0.5em -0.5em -0.5em;
}

.issues li {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
            <li>
                <a>Issues</a>
                <ul class="issues">
                    <li><a>x</a></li>
                    <li><a>y</a></li>
                    <li><a>z</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>Press Releases</a></li>
            <li><a>Donate</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

For example of a better approach, you can use this to prevent suppress by dirty negative margin tricks and for a better, resuable css.

```css
nav > ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul > li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(220, 220, 220), rgb(255, 255, 255));;
    list-style-type: none;
}


.nested{
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.nested li {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: red;
    padding:.5em;

}

ul.parent > li > a
{
   display:block;
   padding:.5em;

}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul class="parent">
            <li>
                <a>Issues</a>
                <ul class="nested">
                    <li><a>x</a></li>
                    <li><a>y</a></li>
                    <li><a>z</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>Press Releases</a></li>
            <li><a>Donate</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Yes I see to fix it I went with putting the padding on the a tag inside the li instead of the li itself. This achieved what I was aiming for thanks.

Comment: Happy to helping you. It may be better if you can tag it as correct answer to reach more people.